# Having as a possesion

Tags: possessives

Can we use Having as possession

1) **i am having a car**

2) **i am having 2 brother**

Answer (score 1):

In most varieties of English *have* can take the continuous form only when it has a meaning other than *possess*. Examples:

> We're having a party next week. (*having* = *organising*, *arranging*, *holding*)
>
> I'm having some difficulties. (*having* = *experiencing*; Present continuous)

I would say "I'm having a car" only in the sense of "I have arranged to hire or borrow a car", and I can't think of any contexts in which I would say "I am having a brother".

However, my impression is that Indian English uses continuous forms more than other varieties, and that sentences like yours are common in Indian English.

Comment: Would it be inconceivable for a young child, with a pregnant mum, to say "I'm having a brother"? Equally an adult might say: "I'm having a new car in April", or "We are having fish & chips for tea", or to a phone caller "I can't talk now I'm having my dinner". But would "having" represent possessing or "acquiring" in those three instances?  Perhaps "yes" in the first two cases, but what about the others?

Comment: @WS2: You're right about having a brother. They're all something other than "possess" in my view.

Comment: *Having* in relation to a person can be a slang term for sex—and it does imply possession. (But that's a special case, and not really relevant to the syntax per se.)

Comment: @JasonBassford A bit dated as well, I would suggest.

Comment: @WS2 Actually, now that I think of it, it's perfectly natural, to use *having* with possession when it comes to food or drink too. *I'm **having** a drink* or *I'm **having** a steak dinner.*

Comment: Isn't that possession as well as an "event"? If I order a drink or make a drink, it's "mine," right? I can actually drink it or not. It's not *just* the activity. (Although it seems to combine the two.)

Comment: Or maybe it's that *I'm having a car* is wrong because it's applied to a noun, and *I'm having a drink* is fine because it applies to a (possible) verb. After all, you could say *I'm having a sip of somebody **else's** drink*, and it would be fine. (And possession or non-possession is a red herring.)

Comment: I don't see "have a drink" as an instance of possession at all, in the normal case. It _can_ have that meaning, with suitable context (eg "I have a drink here ready for you"), but in that sense, it cannot take the continuous, just as I said. In the normal meaning, "have a drink" means no more than "drink something" and does not imply possession. (eg _I had a drink from the water fountain_).

Comment: @ColinFine Yes, like "have a look", or "I'm having a look". "I have a drink" definitely involves possession, but "I'm having a drink" involves process. Unless of course you say "I'm having a drink at the party tonight" which means "I shall have a drink..."

Comment: @WS2: or "I have a drink when I get home every night", which involves process.